# Excel macro find first corresponding value in column

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new with macros and hopeing thet somone can help me with this. It would be highly appriciated.

This is what I am trying to do.

I have a cell with a value in sheet 1, lets say it is cell C2 and it is equal to 1234

I have a column with values in sheet 2, lets say it is column B and it has values (3333,1234,1234,1234,8897,8897,6675)

I want the macro to go through column B in sheet2 and find **the first** cell that corresponds to the cell value in cell C2 sheet1. Then I want to place the marker to steps to the right.

In the example above. C2 value corresponds to B1 (even though there are more, this is the first) and then the marker is placed in B3. Please observe that I want to stop when the first corresponding value is found.

Thank you in advance! :)

/J

Comment: Correct, should be D1. Got support below, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've assume "to steps to the right" as two (2) steps to the right. Hope this helps.
As ever with macro records there's a lot of stuff you might not need there.

```
rngFound = Sheet2.Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Sheet1.Range("C2"), _
    After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Address

Range(rngFound).Offset(0, 2).Select
```

This can be tidied up a bit if you'd like.

Comment: JJJP - tick the answer to earn yourself +2 reputation points!

Comment: This is old but it works!  I'd select the answer if I could.  Thanks